# How to change zstd level for qcow2 image?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, zstd

There is an option `compression_type=zstd` to enable zstd compression for qcow2 [according to wiki](https://wiki.qemu.org/ChangeLog/5.1#:%7E:text=compression_type).

But it always uses `zstd level 3`, how could I do to compress it with `level 19`? This image is read-only and I just want the max compression level.

The command I use now is:

```
qemu-img convert -p -f qcow2 -O qcow2 -c -o compression_type=zstd,preallocation=off win10.qcow2 win10-zstd.qcow2
```

Other info:

```
Linux fedora 5.17.5-300.fc36.x86_64
qemu-img.x86_64 2:6.2.0-9.fc36
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not a command line option, so we need to modify the source code. On On [./block/qcow2-threads.c (QEMU v8.2.0)](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/v8.2.0/block/qcow2-threads.c#L224-L226):

```
  224 |  */
+     | ZSTD_CCtx_setParameter(cctx, ZSTD_c_strategy, ZSTD_btultra2);
+     | ZSTD_CCtx_setParameter(cctx, ZSTD_c_compressionLevel, ZSTD_maxCLevel());
+     | ZSTD_CCtx_setParameter(cctx, ZSTD_c_enableLongDistanceMatching, 1);
  225 | zstd_ret = ZSTD_compressStream2(cctx, &output, &input, ZSTD_e_end);
```

Compiling by yourself or use my [prebuilt binary](https://github.com/kkocdko/kblog/releases/download/simple_storage/qemu-img-zstd-x.zip) (built [on GitHub Actions](https://github.com/kkocdko/utils4linux/blob/master/.github/workflows/qemu-img.yml)).

Now we found `qemu-img` at `./build/softemu`. Try to convert a file:

```bash
./qemu-img convert -p -f qcow2 -O qcow2 -c -o compression_type=zstd win10.qcow2 win10-2.qcow2
```

We got it:

```
[kkocdko@fedora tmpfs]$ ls -l
total 3411264
-rw-r--r--. 1 kkocdko kkocdko 1651638272 Jun 12 01:57  win10-2.qcow2
-rw-r--r--. 1 kkocdko kkocdko 1841496064 May 25 18:21  win10.qcow2
```

> Also posted on [my blog](https://kkocdko.site/post/202206112353).